# facing issue while create new app in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am getting the following error while trying to create a new react app with `create-react-app`.

```
bash
$ npx create-react-app demotech
npx: installed 63 in 50.553s

Creating a new React app in D:\js-tech\reactjs\demotech.

'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting demotech/ from D:\js-tech\reactjs
Done.
```

Comment: This just looks like you are missing `npm` from your machine. Try installing this, or can you include what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to commandLine
2) cd into `c` drive. 
3) Do `node -v`
It should display version of node you have installed. If it doesn't that is the proof that you do not have `node` installed in your PC. Link for Node is

```
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

Make sure you are installing correct version for correct Operating System you have.